# Plotting a column containing lists using Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, plot, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) containing several columns and two of them store a list in each row:

```
Index    list1                             list2
A   [ 0.09173306  0.12331911  0.20057651 ]  [ 0.3128322   0.27153913 ]
D   [ 0.03861522  0.10524985 ]              [ 0.37265687  0.48347806 ]
E   [ 0.02124905  0.01149118 ]              [ 0.04348405  0.17057435  0.37838683  0.37481453 ]
```

I would like to plot these lists as bar graphs using `pandas` built-in `plot` function.

Using

```
df.list1.apply(lambda x:x[0]).plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, ax=bar_ax)
```

I can plot the first element of each list. However, trying

```
df.list1.plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, ax=bar_ax)
```

results in the following error:

```
Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

What I would like to do is, **(1)** plot both list into one single plot like so:

```
df[['list1','list2']].plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, ax=bar_ax)
```

And **(2)** also plot the first elements of each list only into one single bar plot, which I can do like this:

```
df.list1.apply(lambda x:x[0]).plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, ax=bar_ax, color='blue')
df.list2.apply(lambda x:x[0]).plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, ax=bar_ax, color='red')
```

However, this results in the bars being plotted on top of each other (not stacked!) - I want to have them grouped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this `DF` containing values as lists as shown:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1': np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,2)).tolist(), 
                   'list2': np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,3)).tolist()}, 
                   index=list('ABCDE'))
```

[image]

***Q-1*** *Plot both list into one single plot:*

Unstack the `DF` to make the column names appear as index and make individual values present in the list to individual series objects.

```
df_lists = df[['list1','list2']].unstack().apply(pd.Series)
df_lists.plot.bar(rot=0, cmap=plt.cm.jet, fontsize=8, width=0.7, figsize=(8,4))
```

[image]

***Q-2*** *Plot the first elements of each list only into one single grouped bar plot:*

Use [`DF.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to select first element of the required columns to obtain the grouped bar plot.

```
df[['list1','list2']].applymap(lambda x: x[0]).plot.bar(rot=0, color=list('br'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':[[ 0.09173306,  0.12331911,  0.20057651], [ 0.03861522,  0.10524985],[ 0.02124905,  0.01149118 ]],
                   'list2':[[0.3128322,   0.27153913], [0.37265687,  0.48347806], [0.04348405,  0.17057435,  0.37838683,  0.37481453]]},
                   index=['A','D','E'])
```

```
print (df)
                                  list1  \
A  [0.09173306, 0.12331911, 0.20057651]   
D              [0.03861522, 0.10524985]   
E              [0.02124905, 0.01149118]   

                                              list2  
A                           [0.3128322, 0.27153913]  
D                          [0.37265687, 0.48347806]  
E  [0.04348405, 0.17057435, 0.37838683, 0.37481453]
```

**First solution**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.list1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).plot(kind='bar', width=0.9)
plt.show()
```

**Second solution with stack**:

I think you need first reshape data by convert `list` to `Series` by `DataFrame` constructor with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
dfL1 = pd.DataFrame(df.list1.values.tolist(), index=df.index).stack()
print (dfL1)
A  0    0.091733
   1    0.123319
   2    0.200577
D  0    0.038615
   1    0.105250
E  0    0.021249
   1    0.011491

dfL2 = pd.DataFrame(df.list2.values.tolist(), index=df.index).stack()
print (dfL2)
A  0    0.312832
   1    0.271539
D  0    0.372657
   1    0.483478
E  0    0.043484
   1    0.170574
   2    0.378387
   3    0.374815
dtype: float64
```

Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together:

```
df = pd.concat([dfL1, dfL2], axis=1, keys=('list1','list2'))
print (df)
        list1     list2
A 0  0.091733  0.312832
  1  0.123319  0.271539
  2  0.200577       NaN
D 0  0.038615  0.372657
  1  0.105250  0.483478
E 0  0.021249  0.043484
  1  0.011491  0.170574
  2       NaN  0.378387
  3       NaN  0.374815
```

And last [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df[['list1','list2']].plot(kind='bar', width=0.9)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I also used your method based on concat, which was really helpful to plot several more lists

Comment: Its a matter of preference for other users I believe. Thanks again.