# MatPlotLib with custom dictionaries convert to graphs

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib

**Problem:**

I have a [list of ~108 dictionaries named `list_of_dictionary`](https://codeshare.io/a3Xqzm) and I would like to use Matplotlib to generate line graphs.

The dictionaries have the following format (this is one of 108):

```
{'price': [59990, 
           59890,
           60990,
           62990, 
           59990, 
           59690], 
 'car': '2014 Land Rover Range Rover Sport', 
 'datetime': [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 22, 11, 19, 26), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 13, 12, 33), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 28, 12, 39, 24), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 29, 18, 39, 36), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 18, 41, 31), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 12, 39, 7)]
}
```

Understanding the dictionary:

The `car` *2014 Land Rover Range Rover Sport* was priced at:

- `59990` on `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 22, 11, 19, 26)`
- `59890` on `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 13, 12, 33)`
- `60990` on `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 28, 12, 39, 24)`
- `62990` on `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 29, 18, 39, 36)`
- `59990` on `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 18, 41, 31)`
- `59690` on `datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 12, 39, 7)`

**Question:**

With this structure how could one create [mini-graphs with matplotlib](https://python-graph-gallery.com/125-small-multiples-for-line-chart/) (say 11 rows x 10 columns)?

Where each mini-graph will have:

- the title of the graph frome `car`
- *x-axis* from the `datetime`
- *y-axis* from the `price`

**What I have tried:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dictionary)
df = df.set_index('datetime')
print(df)
```

I don't know what to do thereafter...

**Relevant Research:**

- [Plotting a column containing lists using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256820/plotting-a-column-containing-lists-using-pandas)
- [Pandas column of lists, create a row for each list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element)

I've read these multiple times, but the more I read it, the more confused I get :(.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's sensible to try and plot that many plots on a figure. You'll have to make some choices to be able to fit all the axes decorations on the page (titles, axes labels, tick labels, etc...).

but the basic idea would be this:

```
car_data = [{'price': [59990, 
           59890,
           60990,
           62990, 
           59990, 
           59690], 
 'car': '2014 Land Rover Range Rover Sport', 
 'datetime': [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 22, 11, 19, 26), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 13, 12, 33), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 28, 12, 39, 24), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 29, 18, 39, 36), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 30, 18, 41, 31), 
              datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 12, 39, 7)]
}]*108

fig, axs = plt.subplots(11,10, figsize=(20,22)) # adjust figsize as you please

for car,ax in zip(car_data, axs.flat):
    ax.plot(car["datetime"], car['price'], '-')
    ax.set_title(car['car'])
```

Ideally, all your axes could share the same x and y axes so you could have the labels only on the left-most and bottom-most axes. This is taken care of automatically if you add `sharex=True` and `sharey=True` to `subplots()`:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(11,10, figsize=(20,22), sharex=True, sharey=True) # adjust figsize as you please
```