# Can we Plot the Busy hours list of Data frame in Python for data analysis

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataset 1- Restaurants 2- Day , 3- busy_hours and I want to plot the dataset to show the busy hours on the graph. But due to list of numbers of busy hours its showing it but i cannot figure out the analysis with that. Because if the busy_hours column has empty hours its also showing the weighted. Can you please suggest some way for analysis of it.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv("template (3).csv")
df=df.dropna()
df
plt.figure(figsize=(16,7), dpi= 80)
plt.scatter(df.Restuarants, df.busy_hours, s=250, alpha=.6)
plt.show()
```

DataSet image

[image]

Graph Image

[image]

CSV file

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting a column containing lists using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256820/plotting-a-column-containing-lists-using-pandas)

Comment: Hi @scandav I checked the solution which you point out but it has 2 or three number of hours [14,23] , [4,5,2] but in my case the data set contains 3,4,5,6,7 hours dimension. Can you please check this. Thank you